# Safari in app browser huge bounce rate in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, bounce-rate, safari

For the past 7 days I ran a Facebook ad.
Today I decided to track how users behave and I noticed a huge bounce rate coming from Safari In App browser and Android webview. It was 91% as compared to Chrome or Mozilla which are 60%.
I read that many users are reporting the same issue.
Should I be worried and what should I do to fix that? My website load speed is fast when checked in Gmetrix or Pingdom.

Comment: Is your site usable in Safari on mobile devices?

Comment: I don't know how to test this. Please do so if you can and let me know gearuphiking.com